# How to resize a large image and make it fit into UIButton in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, xcode7

I am trying to place a large image on a button after resizing to the exact size of button. I am making use of this code

```
var FB = UIButton(type:UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
var image = UIImage(named: "facebook-logo-png-2.png")
func buttonTouchDown(sender:UIButton!){
    print("button Touch Down")
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  FB.frame = CGRectMake(0,0 , 100, 100)
    FB.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    FB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouchDown(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    FB.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    FB.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(25,25,25,25)
    self.view.addSubview(FB)}
```

I am not getting the desired output. Currently, my output looks like this [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmgVA.png)
[image]
This is my first iOS app, please help me if possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this line

FB.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

Before
self.view.addSubview(FB)

What it does is scale the image to the fit the size while being true to the aspect ratio of the image being set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but It didn't work for me. @Ashif Khan please have a lot  the screen shot given, the image is partially visible(above the first thumbnail)

Comment: i think to make it work, you have to keep the aspect ratio of button same as the image. Can you tell me what is the aspect ratio of the image?

Comment: image dimensions-1600x1209